# Class instance as a private member in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have an assignment where I need to use inheritance and polymorphism:

> For this assignment, we will subclass the author's Time2 class as Time3  and subclass your previous Date2  to include a Time3 instance as a private member.  This new class will be called TimeStamp3 (subclassing Date2 and having a Time3 instance).

I don't entirely understand the part:

> include a Time3 instance as a private member

Although I do understand that `Time3 extends Time2` and `TimeStamp3 extends Date2`,
I just can't figure out what I need to do to allow Date2 to have access to Time3.

Comment: You need to put a `Time3` field in the class you create that extends `Date2`.

Comment: Classes called name{number}. What is education coming to?

Comment: At least they have classes. We only had functions, and thought we were lucky!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class member is also known as an instance variable. Therefore, your `Time3` instance in your `Date2`, would be private or protected, rather than public. It might look like:

```
class TimeStamp3 extends Date2{
...
   private Time3 timeThree; 
...

}
```

You don't have to worry about accessing the `Time3` instance inside `Date2` because it is subclassed. As you should know, when an instance variable is `private`, it is only accessible to members inside the class. This will not make the `Time3` class private, just the specific instance of that object inside the `Date2` class.

Even when the instance member is private, any methods inside the `Date2` class will be able to access that member variable. It's the classes outside of `Date2` that won't be able to access that instance. Other classes could potentially access `Time3`, just not the the instance of `Time3` inside `Date2`.

Answer (score 1):

After creating the Time3 class, create another class called TimeStamp3 (silly names...)

```
public class TimeStamp3 extends Date2 {

    private Time3 time;

    //methods, other instance variables etc.

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this made so much sense. so i have an instance of Time3 called time within my TimeStamp3 class that extends Date2? I get it now!